# Emacs - Python LSP setup.cfg not honored

Tags: python, emacs, language-server-protocol, flycheck, pycodestyle

I'm using vanilla Emacs and I installed `lsp-mode` as follows:

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :config (defun lsp-go-install-save-hooks ()
            (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'lsp-format-buffer t t)
            (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'lsp-organize-imports t t))
  :hook (
         (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
         (go-mode . lsp-deferred)
         (go-mode . lsp-go-install-save-hooks)
         (typescript-mode . lsp-deferred)
         (python-mode . lsp-deferred)
         )
  )
```

For Python I installed [this](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server). Everything seems to be working fine, but the problem is that I'm not able to override the default `pycodestyle` settings. For example, it complains about long lines `> 79` so I tried adding in the root of the project the following `setup.cfg`:

```
[pycodestyle]
max-line-length=99
```

But it's not taken into account, am I missing something? I saw that there's the possibility to change the setting globally, but I'd like to have it on a per-project basis.

**UPDATE**

If `pycodestyle` is ran from the terminal it works as expected: it complains with the default line-length limit and it doesn't if I increase it to a value that is greater to the longest line that I have in the code.

The `*lsp-log*` buffer doesn't seem to provide any meaningful information:

```
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is present on the path.
Command "pyls" is not present on the path.
Command "pylsp" is present on the path.
Found the following clients for /<some path>/sample-app/sample_app/__init__.py: (server-id pylsp, priority -1)
The following clients were selected based on priority: (server-id pylsp, priority -1)
```

If I exec the `flycheck-describe-checker` command this is the output:

```
lsp is a Flycheck syntax checker.

  This syntax checker checks syntax in the major mode(s)
  `python-mode', `lsp-placeholder-mode', and uses a custom predicate.

Documentation:
A syntax checker using the Language Server Protocol (LSP)
provided by lsp-mode.
See https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode.
```

If I disable `flycheck` by executing the command `flycheck-disable-checker` indeed the warnings go away, but it stops all the checks. So it seems like `flycheck` is the responsible for not honoring the `setup.cfg`.

Comment: There are maybe some additional info you need to provide to help people who tries to answer you question.

1) Does `pycodestyle` works in terminal without complain about long lines.
2) Can you check the complain is from lsp. (maybe you are using flycheck, `flycheck-describe-checker`)
3) tried to paste the content of `*lsp-log*`

Comment: Thanks @TianshuWang for the tips on how to investigate this! I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to understand what it seems to be happening. It seems that under the hood `flycheck` is using `flake8` instead of `pycodestyle`. Indeed after I change `setup.cfg` into this:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length=99
```

Everything started working as expected.

The problem is that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server#configuration) of `python-lsp-server` by default it should use `pycodestyle`. Moreover, checking through `flake8` seems to be requiring 3rd party plugins according to the [doc](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server#3rd-party-plugins) that I didn't install.

Not everything works as expected yet, as for example I have some complaints related to `D100` and `D104` that if I put them as ignore in the configuration their not honored yet.

Comment: flycheck seems to auto detect and use several checkers. If you install flake8 and it will use it.

Comment: Indeed it seems so, but still then I don’t get why adding ignore for those docstring-related errors are not honored as well.

Comment: I think the troubleshooting idea is similar, command line, confirm flycheck reads the configuration, and I'm not sure about the rest.